# Find the derivative of a function with new variable

Tags: analysis, derivatives

> Suppose $f(x-3)=(x-2)^2$ and find the $f'(x^2+5)$

When I solve this problem, I first find $f(x)$ by substitute $x=x+3$, i.e. $f(x)=(x+3-2)^2 \implies f(x)=(x+1)^2$. Then I convert $f(x)$ to be $f(x^2+5)$ i.e.  $f(x^2+5)=(x^2+5+1)^2=(x^2+6)^2$. Then I calculate the derivative of $f(x^2+5)=(x^2+6)^2$    $f'(x^2+5)=2(x^2+6)·2x$.

However, this is wrong, and the correct solution is first to find the derivative of $f(x)$ then evaluate the derivative at $x^2+5$ i.e.$f'(x)=2(x+1)$ and $f'(x^2+5)=2(x^2+5+1)=2(x^2+6)$.

My question is why my solution is wrong, and what is the difference between the correct answer and my answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calculated the derivative of the composite function $x\mapsto f(x^2+5)$, and evaluated it at $x$, rather than calculating the derivative of the function $t\mapsto f(t)$, and evaluating it at $x^2+5$. Note that by definition
$$
\left(x\mapsto f(x^2+5)\right)'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f((x+h)^2+5)-f(x^2+5)}{h} \, ,
$$
whereas
$$
(t\mapsto f(t))'(x^2+5)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h}\bigg\rvert_{t=x^2+5}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x^2+5+h)-f(x^2+5)}{h} \, .
$$

Comment: I slightly understand this. Then is there a notation for what I should regard as the independent variable? Just like $f'(x^2+5)$. I interpret this to take the derivative of $f(g(x))$ where $f(x)=(x+1)^2$ and $g(x)=x^2+5$ and the independent variable is $x$, However the question let me take the derivative of $f(g(x))$ and the independent variable is $g(x)$. Is there a way to tell this?

Comment: @Yink: Actually, $f'(x^2+5)$ is just the value of the function $f'$ at a point which we happen to call $x^2+5$. If you want to measure the change to $f(x^2+5)$ as you change the $x$-coordinate, then you should consider the derivative of the function $x\mapsto f(x^2+5)$ at the point $x$, which is not the same thing as $f'(x^2+5)$.

Comment: @Yink: To answer your second question, the idea of treating the output of a function (in this case, $g(x)$) as an independent variable is a little dubious, but it can be done. Generally speaking, by definition $$\frac{df(g(x))}{dg(x)}=\frac{df(u)}{du}\bigg\rvert_{u=g(x)}=f'(g(x)) \, .$$The idea behind this definiton is that we "forget" the fact that $g(x)$ is dependent on $x$, and instead treat it as an independent variable.

Answer (score 1):

As a method to proceed: $f(g(x))’=g’(x)f’(g(x))$. Set $g(x)=x^2+5$. So, $g’(x)=2x$. For $x$ non zero, $f’(x^2+5)=\frac{f(g(x))}{2x}$